# request sparql property function

Tags: sparql, jena

I created this request but does not show the results that can concater with the given name familyName it just displays the givenName and then another line, attorneys in the familyName.
i used jena 3.0 .
why does not work?

```
PREFIX apf:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ/property#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
    SELECT *
    {?Person foaf:givenName ?x .    
    ?Person foaf:familyName ?y .  
    ?name apf:concat (?x " " ?y) }
```

Comment: This looks to be about the data (e.g. contains some empty strings).

Comment: `BIND(concat(?x," ", ?y) AS ?name)` is the same effect but using  standard SPARQL 1.1 functions.

Comment: same result, do not contact the String ,and hasn't empty string.

Comment: display null, does not display the string just the null word 

[PREFIX apf:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ/property#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
   SELECT *
    { 
    ?name apf:concat ("aze" " " "eza")  }]